# Prove that $ PRQS$ is cyclic.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram. $H$ is the Orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$. Points $P\in BC $ and $Q\in AD$ such that $PQ \parallel AB$ with $(PQ)$ passes through $H$, and points $R\in AB $ and $S\in CD$ such that $RS \parallel BC$ with $(RS)$ passes through H. Show that $PRQS$ is cyclic.

Here is a diagram

[image]

If you look carefully, you can see that $\angle QRP$ and $\angle QSP$ are about $90$, so maybe we can try to prove that thing.

$$\angle QRP=180-\angle ARQ-\angle BRP=180-\angle RQH-\angle RPH$$

Same thing with $$\angle QSP=180-\angle HPS-\angle HQS$$

Hence $$\angle QRP+\angle QSP=360-\angle QRH-\angle RPH-\angle HPS-\angle HQS$$
But to get that $QRP+QSP+180$ You have to prove $\angle RPS+ \angle RQS=180$. It's the same thing if you tried to prove $\angle SRP=\angle SQP$. Maybe this problem is beyond Angle Chasing?

Comment: Can you label the points in your picture?

Comment: How is $H$ relevant to the question? IE Do you want $PHQ$ to be a straight line? $\quad$ Show that $PQRS$ what? $\quad$ By symmetry, if $QRP$ is a right angle, then so is $RPQ$. Hence, that assumption is not true, and it's just a result of the triangle $ABC$ that you chose. Move those vertices around.

Comment: Is it given that parallel lines to $AB$ and $BC$ are drawn through $H$? I think that should be the case but you have not stated it in your question. If yes, you can use similar triangles to show equal inscribed angles by segment $PS$ at point $Q$ and $R$.

Comment: That's the same as saying that $PQ \parallel AB$ and $RS \parallel BC$ @MathLover

Comment: No it isn't the same. Your question is not complete  Why can P not be midpoint of BC and Q midpoint of AD?

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited that. @MathLover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you could prove this by proving $QH\times HP=RH\times HS$ without looking at the angles.

This is equivalent to $AR/RH=PC/PH$ since $AR=QH$ and $SH=PC$.

Now, notice that $H$ is orthocenter, we have $\angle BAH=90^\circ-\angle ABC=\angle BCH$, so we have $\angle PAH=\angle PCH$. Furthermore, since $AR\parallel PH$ and $RH\parallel PC$ we have $\angle ARH=\angle CPH$. Thus, we have $\triangle ARH\sim\triangle CPH$, and therefore $AR/RH=PC/PH$

Comment: You didn't quote 'The Power of a Point'?

Comment: @Yassir Ah... TBH I don't even know there is a name that the property called, since I used this property to prove cyclic by proving similar triangles...